# Does grep --color default to =auto or =always?

Tags: grep, colors

What is the default color behavior for `grep --color` if no [*=WHEN*] is specified?

The grep [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control) states:

> `--color`[=*WHEN*], `--colour`[=*WHEN*]
>
>   Surround the matched (non-empty) strings, matching lines, context lines,
>              file names, line numbers, byte offsets, and separators (for fields and
>              groups of context lines) with escape sequences to display them in color
>              on the terminal. 
>              ...
>   *WHEN*
>   is
>   **`never`**
>   ,
>   **`always`**
>   , or
>   **`auto`**
>   .

Does the default [*=WHEN*] for `grep --color` become:

```
grep --color=auto
```

or

```
grep --color=always
```

or does it depend on implementation and platform?

In my tests on Ubuntu 14.04 with GNU grep 2.16:

```
echo "foo bar" | \grep --color foo
```

results in **`foo`**`bar`, while

```
echo "foo bar" | \grep --color foo | \grep --color bar
```

results in `foo`**`bar`**, so it appears that `grep --color=auto` is in effect here. I have not tested this on Windows or Mac, however; I don't know if this behavior is universal.

This default for [*=WHEN*] is a little different from `ls --color` where the man page for `ls` states:

> `--color`[=*WHEN*]
>
>   colorize the output.
>   *WHEN*
>   defaults to
>   **`always`**
>   or can be
>   **`never`**
>   or
>   **`auto`**
>   .

Here, the behavior of the missing *WHEN* is explicit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It defaults to `auto`.

`grep --color` is the same as writing `--color=auto`.

This seems to be deficiently documented, or they consider the simple `--color` deprecated, but that can be seen both from testing and from [its source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c?id=41ac7a99647316b5ea77d70199282fa9bbd731d4#n2695):

```
  case COLOR_OPTION:
    if (optarg)
      {
        if (!strcasecmp (optarg, "always") || !strcasecmp (optarg, "yes")
            || !strcasecmp (optarg, "force"))
          color_option = 1;
        else if (!strcasecmp (optarg, "never") || !strcasecmp (optarg, "no")
                 || !strcasecmp (optarg, "none"))
          color_option = 0;
        else if (!strcasecmp (optarg, "auto") || !strcasecmp (optarg, "tty")
                 || !strcasecmp (optarg, "if-tty"))
          color_option = 2;
        else
          show_help = 1;
      }
    else
      color_option = 2;
    break;
```

Notice that the lack of an `optarg` results in the same as it being equal to `auto` or `tty`.